# Send email if new values were added from android app to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to make some code to automaticly send an email to my adress if new values from my application were added to firebase database.
It has to be something like feedback, but google canceled sending emails from android studio applications as an uknown source.
Is there any solution for my problem ?

And sorry for my english ;D

I tried send email from android studio to email address but it didn't work.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-install-and-use-trigger-email-extension-from-firebase-f6f9763c8088) might help.

Comment: And this example from Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/email-confirmation